# GKE cluster creation fails because the network "default" does not have available private IP space in 10.0.0.0/8 to reserve a /14 block

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I was trying to create a GKE cluster and it failed with the error

```
GKE cluster creation fails because the network "default" does not have available private IP space in 10.0.0.0/8 to reserve a /14 block
```

I'm assuming this is because I already have a bunch of clusters running and each cluster consumes some amount of address space. But I don't understand CIDR notation well enough to understand how this limits the number of clusters I can create simultaneously.

Could some please explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 64 /14 ranges in the 10.0.0.0/8 IP space. But you can't actually create that many clusters because the VMs themselves use up a /16 range that cannot be reused by a cluster because the IPs for the pods would overlap with IPs assigned to VMs. You also need a *contiguous* /14 block (262k IP addresses) for your cluster.

If you don't have an available /14 range in your network, you can ask for a smaller range to be assigned for your cluster (using the `--cluster-ipv4-cidr` flag) with the caveat that you must provide the explicit block (e.g. 10.0.0.0/16) rather than letting GKE choose one for you.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Is the number of blocks available affected by the number of node pools? For example, would a GKE cluster with 2 node pools use up more blocks than a GKE cluster with 1 node pool?

Comment: No, it's just the number of clusters. The /14 is divided up among pods in the cluster, which can reside on any of the node pools in the cluster. Also note that the /14 only allows you to scale to ~1000 nodes (because each node gets a /24 allocated) so if you want to scale to a larger cluster you'll need to use the aforementioned flag to provide a larger CIDR range.

Comment: @RobertBailey can you help with a question I asked in GKE tag? thanks